# PHP SimpleXML: How can I load an HTML file?

Tags: php, html, simplexml

When I try to load an HTML file as XML using [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) I get many errors and warnings regarding the HTML and it fails, it there a way to properly load an html file using SimpleXML?

This HTML file may have unneeded spaces and maybe some other errors that I would like SimpleXML to ignore.

Comment: 'tis wrong to use simplexml to parse html pages, though

Comment: @silent: What about xhtml? isn't this supposed to be valid xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). I've used it myself for anything from page scraping to manipulating HTML template files and its very simple and quite powerful and should suit your needs just fine.

Here's a few examples from their docs that show the kind of things you can do:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: I've had problems with Simple DOM because it uses the PHP DOM extension internally, and it wont load completly broken HTML pages.

Comment: could always clean the content first with PHP Tidy http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: @Quamis: That's wrong, Simple DOM is *not* based on the PHP DOM extension.

Comment: -1: This answer does not show how to load that HTML into a SimpleXMLElement. Bad for future visitors searching for it.

Answer (score 20):

Use `DomDocument::loadHtmlFile` together with `simplexml_import_dom` to load non-wellformed HTML pages into SimpleXML.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some quick code to load an external html page, then parse it with simple xml.

```
    //suppresses errors generated by poorly-formed xml
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    //create the html object
    $html = new DOMDocument();

    //load the external html file
    $html->loadHtmlFile('http://blahwhatever.com/');

    //import the HTML object into simple xml
    $shtml = simplexml_import_dom($html);

    //print the result
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($shtml);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) man page, one of those options (LIBXML_NOERROR for example) might help you.. but keep in mind that a html is not necessarily a valid xml, so parsing it as xml might not work.