# How can I remove html attributes from xml file in php?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing, simplexml

I have a XML file that has HTML in it. Within the HTML tags there are attributes I'd like to remove, yet I need to keep all of the tags. An example would be:

```
<description><![CDATA[<div><span style='font-size: 40px'>Testing123</span></div>]]></description>
```

I'd like to remove the 'style' attribute so that the output is:

```
 <description><![CDATA[<div><span>Testing123</span></div>]]></description>
```

I was sort of able to get this working using **preg_replace**, but then the formatting was way off when I went to save the file. In other words, I want to preserve the formatting of the XML file after the parsing/stripping of my file.

**EDIT: The initial sample data I provided doesn't include  CDATA that is within my XML file. I modified that.**

Comment: Do you want to remove all of the attributes - or just specific ones from specific tags?

Comment: A solution that uses XSLT would be the best for the task.

Comment: @NigelRen - I'd like to move all attributes except for one tag. How can this be accomplished? For example, suppose I want to keep <div id="SomeId>contents</div>, but for all other HTML tags I want to remove the attributes. Any easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the formatting, but try using simplexml and the unset() function:

```
$string = "<div><span style='font-size: 40px'>Testing123</span></div>";                                                                       
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$target = $xml->xpath("//span/@style");
foreach ($target as $node) {
    unset($node[0]);
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div><span>Testing123</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<transform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"/>
 <mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
 <template match="span/@style"/>
</transform>
```

You can extend the match pattern, or add additional template rules, depending which attributes you want to remove.

Of course XSLT 1.0 is possible as well, it's just a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the string from the cdata element as XML ([more correct: HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502335/367456)) and then remove all the attributes, for example with xpath:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
$cdata = simplexml_load_string((string)$xml);
foreach ($cdata->xpath('@*[name(.) != "id"]|*/@*') as $attribute) {
    unset($attribute[0]);
}
```

(compare: *an answer to [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/367456)*)

Then, if you need to preserve the CDATA element, you have to do a DOM-round-trip as SimpleXML does not have CDATA sections, but DOMDocument has:

```php
    if ($n = dom_import_simplexml($el)) {
        $cd = $n->ownerDocument->createCDATASection($data);
        $n->appendChild($cd);
    }
```

(compare: *[How to write CDATA using SimpleXmlElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260224/367456)*; check the PHP manual for even more details)

You also need to create the XML from `$cdata` but you want to drop the first line as it contains the [XML declaration](https://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml).

```php
    rtrim(explode("\n", $el->asXML(), 2)[1]);
```

(compare: **SimpleXML Line Separator** in *[SimpleXML Type Cheatsheet](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/simplexml-type-cheatsheet/)*)

Given an input like:

```php
$buffer=<<<XML
<description><![CDATA[<div id="2" style="all: inherit;"><span style='font-size: 40px'>Testing123</span></div>]]></description>
XML;
```

the result is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<description><![CDATA[<div id="2"><span>Testing123</span></div>]]></description>
```

[Example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SUnNV); Output for 7.3.0 - 7.3.29, 7.4.0 - 7.4.21, 8.0.0 - 8.0.8:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<description><![CDATA[<div id="2"><span>Testing123</span></div>]]></description>
```